# Unable to include file in the spec file

Tags: ruby, rspec, sketchup

I am trying to write an RSpec test for a ruby project(Sketchup plugin) but I am facing an issue with the `require`.

Below is how my folder is structured

[image]

In my `smoke_tests_spec.rb`

```
require "main_folder/subfolder1/file_to_test.rb"
```

When I run the rspec using `rspec-core/rspec` from the root directory I get the following error

```
Failure/Error: require "main_folder/subfolder1/file_to_test.rb"

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- main_folder/subfolder1/file_to_test.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `LOAD_PATH` or use `require_relative`

[Here](https://medium.com/@ellishim/understanding-require-vs-require-relative-vs-require-all-80e3b26d89e6) you have more info.